# Image not loaded in ImageView

Tags: android, image

Today I received a complaint for an app that I made. Basically, the problem is that I have an `ImageView` which loads an image from the resources directory, but sometimes, the image is not loaded and a white space is displayed instead. The only complaint comes from Sony Xperia Z3 with the Android version 5.1.1. The drawable is added only for `xhdpi`, but I know that if needed Android scales it to the corresponding resolution. Do you have any ideas why this could take place since I wasn't able to reproduce the bug? Also, here's my `ImageView` code but I'm sure that there is no problem.

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:background="@drawable/green_logo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use background for ImageView? Use `android:src="@drawable/image"`.

Comment: Hmmm... Good point! It looks like I missed that since this part isn't written by me, but is it normal to happen even if it is set as background? I checked the differences between them and beside some scale and something else, there was nothing that could do, at least this in my opinion. What do you think about this?